# Use the device's internal memory

Tags: android

Can I use the internal memory to store your application files there? In other words, when suddenly, the device will not SD card. In particular, I need to create there a folder where I was later going to copy your files.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
String packagePath = "/data/"+getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/<your folder name>"
```

A folder will be created in the application's package. This folder will be in-accessible by other applications and hence it will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path=context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/filename";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path =/data/data/your.package.name/

ex: path =/data/data/com.pack1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes surely, you can use Internal  memory for storing pupose. But as per my opinion you should not use it as in some devices has very small amount of Internal Memory.